# WP function to change CPT archive title

Tags: php, wordpress

in my custom post type (documents), I want to change the default page title (not the meta title) to a custom title. I tried several posts about it but it never works. Here'S what I have so far:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_archive_title', function( $title ) {
if ( is_category( 'documents' ) ) {
    $title = 'Bibiliothèque virtuelle';
}

return $title;
}, 50 );
```

But I still see the default title
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this a custom post type or a regular post?

Comment: in my custom post type ...

Comment: can you show the taxonomy definition?  `is_category` won't work for a custom taxonomy.

Comment: Sorry, I dont use categories in this section. All I want is to display a custom title in the CPT archive instead of 'documents'.

Comment: Then why do you think that `is_category('documents')` would return true for your archive page?  What is the custom post type... can you add this to your question?  Remember there's three ways to do things; the right way, the wrong way and the Max Power way!